# Trouble transferring files to Ubuntu server from mac

Tags: 12.04, server, files, mac, webmin

I am trying to setup my first home server and haven't had too much trouble so far.  However I can't seem to find a way to transfer files from my laptop (Macbook Pro) to the server.

I have been able to mount the drive and open the folder in Finder.  When I go to copy a file I receive a popup window that states "Finder wants to make changes.  Type your password to allow this." I then enter my laptop's password and receive another message saying "The operation can't be completed because you don't have permission to acces some of the items."

I am connected to the server using my registered user account, am running Ubuntu server version 12.04.2, and using webmin.  Any help with correcting this problem would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You can use filezilla to transfer through ssh

Comment: filezilla worked great.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem. To solve it I used `sudo chmod 777 filename` to give my shared directory read write access.

[Here](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_file_permissions) is a good link about checking permissions.

Even with the "Read-only?" radial button "No" selected In the Edit Exports page and "Volume access" set to "read/write" for my logical volumes I couldn't successfully drag a file into my shared folders until using `sudo chmod 777 filename`.